# How to make a Google Scripts like UI

Tags: jquery-ui, user-interface, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to make an extension for the Google Drive app. My app will be hosted on Google app engine and I would like to keep the UI design as close to the default Google styling as possible. 
I've tried using the dev tools to get a better understanding of the way the page looks but because pretty much all of it is dynamic and coded in JS it's hard to get an accurate understanding.

What I would like to know is if there is some sort of library or framework I could use to create a standard looking Google Drive editor similar to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bERKz.png)

Comment: I can't follow your link - I get *you don't have permission to access this item*.  Are you sure that link is available to people other than you?

Comment: It must not be. I'll replace it with an image. But to see it on your profile (if you have a google account) you must go to Google Drive and  create a new "google scripts" document.

Comment: Switched the link to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Google Drive UI but you can create a Chrome-like UI by using [Chrome UI bootstrap](https://github.com/roykolak/chrome-bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

The styling is not openly available and I'm not sure but it may be a copyright issue if you imitate it by inspecting the page.